# verbs for sentence beginning there

Tags: lists

There was a sword and shield by the lion. There were a sword and a shield by the lion. Which of the two is correct? Both sound awkward.

Comment: Consider "There was a sword and **a** shield by the lion".

Comment: Or consider using a verb other than _be_, which is the only English verb that has a different form for a plural subject in the past tense. Almost any locative or dispositive predicate will work with [_There_-Insertion](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3a15299%20there%20insertion); there's [a very large list](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/thereins.vbs.html). For instance, _There lay a sword and (a) shield by the lion._

Comment: @SovereignSun, your possible duplicate is not the same because both bruises and cuts are plural. In this example both shield and lion as singular.

Comment: @JavaLatte In a way you are right. But in a way there are two objects and while both are singular the choice between was and were is the same as between was and were with all.

Answer (score 0):

Either **"was"** or **"were"** is possible and neither sounds awkward.

1. **"was"** if you are rendering the two objects as a whole or if you want to emphasize a group.

   - There was [a sword and a shield] by the lion. *(A sword and a shield act as one object)*
2. **"were"** if you are rendering each object separate from the others or if you want to emphasize the individual objects.

   - There were [a sword] and [a shield] by the lion. *(There were two things one of which was a sword and the other was a shield)*

However, as says this rule **"The choice between the phrases there is and there are at the beginning of a sentence is determined by the noun that follows it.**" I tend to use the plural form **"were"** with multiple objects if the first noun is plural and the singular form "was" if the first noun is singular.

- There were three pencils, two books, and a pen on the table.
- There was a vase, three flowers in it, and postcard at the side.

---

- **Sword and shield** mostly refers to **fencing with a sword and a shield**, **a category of melee weapons**, **a combination of the two** *(especially as arming or a symbol)* or [**sexual activity**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sword%20and%20shield).